# Is there any way to remove the timecode from an .srt file on my S3?

Tags: editing

I want to remove the timecode  from an .srt file so I can just copy and paste the text into a document.  Is there a way to achieve this without manually deleting each line?

S3
4.1.1

Comment: You might wish to check for an editor app which supports Search-and-Replace by [RegExps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: @Izzy:  But how would that work?  I don't want to replace but I'm looking for something that can strip a .srt file of it's timecodes just to be left with words.

Comment: Sure: Replacing the timecode with "nothing" would be the same as removing/stripping it, right? See [geffchang's answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/52218/16575): His command removes lines consisting of nothing but digits. `^` is start of line, `$` is end of line, and `[0-9]+` means "one or more of the characters from 0 to 9". `/` is the delimiter, and `d` says to delete. For the curly braces and the N you need to ask geffchang, I never saw that notation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to provide a suggestion, but it's not an Android app.

You can try [subeditnet](https://code.google.com/p/subeditnet/):

> A simple tool to add or remove time to a SRT subtitle file. I
>   developed this in my spare time, so don't expect it to be completely
>   bug free. Please always BACKUP your .srt file ;)
>
> You will need Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 to execute it on older
>   Operating Systems.

Or [via Linux command](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/how-can-i-extract-plain-text-from-a-srt-file-subtitle-by-eliminating-the-time-codes-4175467742/) (not tested):

> $ dos2unix subtitles.srt
>   $ sed -r '/^[0-9]+$/{N;d}' subtitles.srt > outfile

Comment: Why is it not Android related?  I need to do this on my phone hence the question.

Comment: @verve In that case, it is Android-related, but so far I haven't found anything that will do what you want. Windows apps may be your best bet for now.

Comment: Assuming the linux command is correct, you just need to install busybox and a terminal emulator from the play store. It's also possible that dos2unix and sed are already available (without busybox) but you may need to do some extra work to find the right path to the tools. You'll also need to make sure you have write permission for the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

As explained it the comments to the question, and indicated by [geffchang's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/52218/16575), what you need for that is an editor supporting regular expression search and replace. An example for such is [Jota+ Text Editor](http://www.appbrain.com/app/jota-%28text-editor%29/jp.sblo.pandora.jota.plus), supporting that for Android 2.2 onwards.

To learn more about Regular Expressions, see [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), which also provides additional links. To teach them would go beyond the scope of this site, but the examples given might already work out for you.